# Access 2016 Query for subtraction in same table same column

Tags: ms-access, join, subquery

i have table that have values in it i need to calculate one field which the subtruction of two rows values, i have writen the below query but it is not working and throughing a JOIN error.

```
UPDATE TempTbl, ((SELECT TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE (((TempTbl.PHD_TAG)="31FC1064.PV")))-(SELECT TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE (((TempTbl.PHD_TAG)="31FC2064.PV")))) AS A SET TempTbl.Cal_Value = "A"
WHERE (((TempTbl.ASSET_DESC)="OAG net flaring"));
```

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Your joined table has to be a table and not a value

Also you must take care, that your subselect only return 1 Value always, or else you get ab error

This Version is for MySQL

```
UPDATE 
TempTbl, (SELECT
           (SELECT TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE TempTbl.PHD_TAG ="31FC1064.PV" LIMIT 1)
           - (SELECT TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE TempTbl.PHD_TAG="31FC2064.PV" LIMIT 1)
           ) AS A 
SET TempTbl.Cal_Value = "A"
WHERE (TempTbl.ASSET_DESC="OAG net flaring");
```

And this for Access

```
UPDATE 
TempTbl, (SELECT
           (SELECT TOP 1 TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE TempTbl.PHD_TAG ="31FC1064.PV" )
           - (SELECT TOP 1 TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE TempTbl.PHD_TAG="31FC2064.PV" )
           FROM TempTbl) AS A 
SET TempTbl.Cal_Value = "A"
WHERE (TempTbl.ASSET_DESC="OAG net flaring");
```

I added a version this shouölb give you a hint how you can make such a query

```
UPDATE 
TempTbl INNER JOIN (SELECT TempTbl.ASSET_DESC
,(SELECT TOP 1 TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE TempTbl.PHD_TAG ="31FC1064.PV" )
-(SELECT TOP 1 TempTbl.Cal_Value FROM TempTbl WHERE TempTbl.PHD_TAG ="31FC1064.PV" )
FROM TempTbl
WHERE (((TempTbl.PHD_TAG)="31FC1064.PV"))
) AS A ON A.ASSET_DESC = TempTbl.ASSET_DESC
SET TempTbl.Cal_Value = "A"
WHERE (TempTbl.ASSET_DESC="OAG net flaring");
```

Comment: it is giving an error "Query Input Must Contain At Least one table or query"

Comment: access is a bit more complicated, i changed the answer

Comment: its working but is shows multiple empty rows, i am using the Access Query

Comment: that is not part of the question as you make a Cross join, you wl als get multiple result sets.  but that has nothing to do with the question

Comment: the aim is to get one calculated figure and update the other field in the table, all these values in different rows but in same table under one column Cal_Value, appreciate your help, also currently it is returning no value only empty row

Comment: An Update can't return a value when you run the query in access you get a message how many rows are affected. So i can't get multiple rows it no select